# Get a info about coloured pixels at gray image. Python, opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have small r g b image. Imake it gray.

```
original = cv2.imread('im/auto5.png')
print(original.shape)  # 27,30,3 
print(original[13,29]) # [254 254 254]
orig_gray = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(orig_gray.shape) # 27,30
```

Is it in this array info about white and black pixels? Or it lost this data? What mean this numbers?

```
print(orig_gray[5,5]) #6
```

At r g b image it mean color (3 digits, like [254,254,254]). But what mean one digit in my case with gray image? I want to get quanity of white pixels for my recognising.

Comment: In a greyscale image, `0` means black and `255` means white, so `6` means almost black.

Answer (score 1):

Once you convert to gray scale there is only one value for each 'pixel' or index in the 2D array which represents the brightness in the original RGB image.  The RGB image is essentially 3 of these arrays which represent the brightness for each of the three colors.

The idea of a 'white pixel' is a little confusing.  I guess you could say any location in the grayscale array with a value of 255 is a white pixel.  That would be an RGB pixel which is fully saturated at (255, 255, 255). There is basically only one value for each pixel after converting to gray scale.

Hope that helps.